# Old version of Firefox is reinstalled in background about once a day

Tags: firefox

Every morning my browser freezes and fails make new requests. If I try to restart Firefox without reinstalling it, I get a warning telling me that I'm running an older version and that I have to create a new profile.

After some digging I've noticed that a "new" (old) version has been installed in the background. When this happens, I have a fresh install.log that shows the installation of an old version. Not very old, but it seems to be the previous major version.

I'm wondering; is this a bug/glitch in the auto update feature of Firefox, or is there something else that swoops in and installs this version?

If I uninstall Firefox, it is not automatically reinstalled.

When I reinstall, and then checks for a new version, it tells me everything is OK and that I'm using the latest version.

How can I track this down? It surely is annoying to reinstall every day.

Comment: Have yo tied reaching out to their support team?

Comment: Warning is for old version of Firefox, or old version of your profile? What is FF version that has the problem? And have you copied your profile folder forward over time? Format and content structure do change. In your question you need to clarify which versions happened when.

Comment: @Mastaxx I eventually noticed that a Intune process was running at the same time, and reached out to someone administrating that. Turned out that they had a bug in the configuration that accept newer versions, but had pinned it to an old one.